# Where to apply app setting for UITableViewCell / custom cell appearance

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm adding an alternative style selection for my app, which is accessible from my in-app settings screen. The user can select dark or light color schemes.

So far I've used the `initWithStyle:` within the `UITableViewCell` to set the colors.

However, once the view is loaded, even when the user switches views via my navigation controller, the custom table cell class won't be initialised again.

So I need to use an event like `viewWillAppear:` instead, but there doesn't appear to be such an event for a `UITableViewCell`. What should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITableViewDelegate` protocol has a `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`
 message, if that's what you're looking after.